# Rappeler vs Appeler

Tags: verbes

when I wanna' call someone on the phone, let's say a friend of mine, would I use "*Je te rappeler*" or "*Je t'appeler*"?

Comment: Whyever this got closed: The question has been answered anyway and I looked the words up in the dictionary. Both meanings were the same, hence the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Rappeler" is "calling back / calling again".
So if this is the first call, use "appeler" : "Je t'appelle."

Generally speaking, prepending a verb with "re-" or "r-" mean "doing the action again", like "revenir", "reprendre", "refaire", "racheter".

If you need to cut mid-call and plan to call the person again, you would say "Je te rappelle (dans 5 minutes)".

Answer (score 2):

None of the above.

If you mean you reply to or renew a recent call, that would be:

> *Je te rappelle...* (I call you back)

If this call is unrelated to a previous one:

> *Je t'appelle...* (I call you)

Answer (score 1):

"Rappeler" is not used for "to call" and the verb must be conjugated, it cannot be in the infinitive.

When the call is going to be made some time after the person is being told they are going to be called, the present and the future can be used; there is just one exception.

- Nous sommes aujourd'hui vendredi, je t'appelle**rai**/appell**e** dimanche dans l'après-midi, ce qui te donnera deux jours pour réfléchir.
- Je t'appeller**ai**/appell**e** demain.
- Je t'appeller**ai**/appell**e** dans un instant.
- Je t'/appell**e** tout de suite. (*The future is not possible here because "tout de suite" denotes a very short instant; if the future were used the sentence would mean something else (in an other context).*)